# argument of type 'int' is not iterable

Tags: python

I am having a list with int values, iterating the same list with a loop, while iterating it I want to check the list, with some if condition, but am getting this issue:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

My code:

```
list_b=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]  #list with int values

for m in list_b:  #storing the list in m
    print(m) #printing the m

for m in list_b:  # again storing the same list in m
    if(10 in m): #checking for presance of 10 in the list
        print('yes 10 is presant in listb')

    else:
        print('10 is not presant in list_b')
```

Comment: Do either `if 10 in list_b` or stay in your loop and do `if m == 10`

Comment: What did you mean by `10 in m`? On the first iteration `m` is 1, so what is `10 in 1`?

Comment: `for m in list_b` absolutely does not "store the list in m"; it stores the *elements* of the list, one at a time, in `m`.  The `if`/`else` at the end of your code should stand alone, it does not belong inside a `for` loop because you're only doing one test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have fundamentally misunderstood what `for` does. You seem to think that `for m in list_b` means "store `list_b` in `m`". But what it actually means is "go through each element of `list_b`, and for each of them, temporarily store that value in `m`, and then execute the code in the for-loop". So whatever you write in the for-loop gets executes once for every element of `list_b`. So if you just want to print `list_b` and check whether `10` is in `list_b`, you should get rid of the for-loops:

```py
list_b=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]  # list with int values
print(list_b) # printing the m
if (10 in list_b): # checking for presance of 10 in the list
    print('' yes 10 is presant in list_b')
else:
    print('10 is not presant in list_b')
```

PS "presence" and "present" don't have "a", they have "e".

Comment: i Tried this type earlier,but i want to check the same thing loops,the issue for me is had tried the same stuff with a list with string values,which it got executed and given me the expected o/p,but it was not working in intiger values..

Answer (score 2):

So `in` is a keyword meant to iterate across an iterable data type, such as a list or string, and check if your variable is within that iterable. So you can use it like so:

```
ch = "cheese"
ref = "cheese, milk, eggs"
if ch in ref:
    print(True)
    #Prints True
```

or

```
ch = 1
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
if ch in l:
    print(True)
    #Prints True
```

But you can't iterate across an `int`, it's just one integer, so there's the source of your error

Comment: That's a nice description of how `in` works, but I am missing the connection to the question. It doesn't still tell OP how to solve the problem...

Comment: Yeah I could've been more explicit, but the idea is OP's line of ```for m in list_b``` is not setting ```m``` to be the list as they commented in their code